# how to get html element id in vue @click?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm beginner in Vue and i need to get button id which i set it like the code below:

```
<li v-for="subject in this.$root.$data.LoggedUserSubjects">
          <button :style="btnStyleObject" :id="subject.subject.id" @click="showSessions(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">{{subject.subject.name}}</button>
</li>
```

as you can see i need to pass the id to showSessions function but i get this error when i click the button

**Cannot read property 'id' of null**

how can i get the id

thanks a lot

Comment: Without having more context - I'm guessing it's throwing an error on `this.id` ? change that to `subject.subject.id`.

Comment: yes that's right subject.subject.id did it ...thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` will have a scope of the entire component. If there is no id declared in the script section, it will throw an error.

Here, you can directly send the id to the function as follows,

```
<li v-for="subject in this.$root.$data.LoggedUserSubjects">
    <button :style="btnStyleObject" :id="subject.subject.id" @click="showSessions(subject.subject.id)" class="btn btn-primary">{{subject.subject.name}}</button>
</li>
```

Or you can call the function without any parameters and get the target item as follows

```
<li v-for="subject in this.$root.$data.LoggedUserSubjects">
    <button :style="btnStyleObject" :id="subject.subject.id" @click="showSessions" class="btn btn-primary">{{subject.subject.name}}</button>
</li>
```

Inside the method:

```
showSessions:function(e){
   console.log(e.target.id); // this will give you the id of the target element.
}
```